# How do I understand this solution for finding $\lim_{n\to\infty} {1/n}^{1/n}$?

Tags: limits

I don't understand the solution that was given for finding this limit in my textbook. In particular, I don't understand the connection between the result after taking the natural log and the final limit that is determined. I'm also surprised that after taking the natural log and rearranging the exponent, a negative sign pops out in front on the right hand side of the equation. Can anyone explain?

Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}^\frac{1}{n}$.

We first find $$\ln \frac{1}{n}^{\frac{1}{n}} = −\frac{1}{n} \ln n.$$

Then, since we know that the limit as n goes to infinity of $\frac{\ln n}{n}$ is $0$, it follows that the original limit is $e^0 = 1$.

Comment: The negative pops out because $\ln(1/n) = \ln(n^{-1}) = -\ln(n)$.

Comment: exponential and logarithm are continuous functions so $\lim\exp{f)}=\exp(\lim{f})$

Comment: Thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negative sign comes from $\ln(1/n)=-\ln(n).$

The final derivation comes from the continuity of the exponential function: if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{a_n}=e^0$ (here, $a_n=-\frac1n\ln n$ and $e^{a_n}=(1/n)^{(1/n)}$).